# Loop Through Records in a view using X++ AX 2012 R2

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Loop through records in a View Ax 2012 R2( Need a job to achieve this)

I have a viewA where i have three fields
Destination , Source, FieldX

I have a table where i have master list for Source
This table contains S1, S2.....

In the view for each S1 i need to find the final Destination Value
Example: 
Destination Source Type 
D1 S1 
D2 D1 
D2 No record found
Explanation for above example: I took S1 from master list and placed in Source field in View.
then I read Destination value for that Record which is D1. Now I placed D1 in the source field filter
and i found a record with destination value D2. Now i took D2 and i placed
it in the source field filter and i didnt find a record. i stop the loop here and i had 
to save D2 value.

For S1 , the final Destination value is D2.

Example 2:

Destination Source Type 
da s2 
db da 
dc db 
dc No record found

For S2, the final Destination value is Dc.

I am not sure how i should loop in view for S1 to find the D2. 
I had to do this process one by one for all S1,s2.....Sn.

I tried few things using while/for or other loops with no luck. 
Can someone help me with a base code to acheive this?

Comment: This is StackOverflow...add some code you've tried. Search through the AOT for how AX uses views for some base examples.

Comment: After showing your attempt, Edit the question and create sample tables with your scenario and state the desired output. That would be quicker to answer.

Answer (score 1):

How is the "final Destination Value" determined? What logic are you using to determine if a value is a "final Destination Value"? Is it complex logic or is it simply the largest value for that Source? Could you just join the view to the table and use a maxOf(Destination) on the view with a group by on the Source field?

Assuming it is not complex logic, something like this might be possible:

```
ViewA viewA;
Table table;

while select maxOf(Destination) from viewA
    group by viewA.Source
    join table
        where viewA.Source == table.Source

info(strFmt("%1", ViewA.Destination));
```

Comment: While looping through the view using the Destination values, there will be a time when we keep destination value in source field and there wont be any record. Then we consider it as final destination. For Example: View   
DestinationField  SourceField RecId  other fields
MA1             M12  aaa
SA1             MA1  bbb
MB1             M22  ccc
SB1   MB1  ddd
CD1   SB1  eee

If you consider only above records exist in the view.

Comment: I got two values in table M12 and M22. 
So i took M12 and placed in search filter for source then i found Record AAA. 
THen i took MA1 and placed in search filter for source and i found record BBB
Then i took SA1 and placed in search filter for source i didnt find any record.
So the final destination for M12 is SA1. 

Same process for M22 record. tHEN FINAL DESTINATION FOR m22 RECORD IS cd1.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand you, but I believe that if you can't put the logic in the select/query statement, you likely have no choice but to have a loop in a loop to go through all the records in the view and compare to all records in the table. If there are no matching records, you will need logic in the outer loop to satisfy the condition you speak of where there won't be any record.

Comment: I am looking for a code like after executing a select statement, i want to execute two lines and then go back to previous select statement. Not sure how can i achieve this? Any idea?

Comment: That's not possible. I do not think you are designing the solution correctly, although I suppose it's possible that you are working with a nightmare dataset. You need to explain precisely what it is you are trying to accomplish, and the *condition* or *conditions* that you encounter that would make you "go back to the previous select", and also what *condition* that you know that the "previous select" is the "select" that you wish to operate on.

Comment: My actual requirement is the PeggingId. For a planned order, pegging can be from different sources like SO, Planned order, transfer order etc. It can be multilevels deep. So i had to find the peggingId. I created a view where i can find next level for each one. So i need to loop through each record to find the final peggingId for that planned order. Does it makes sense?

Comment: This sounds like an excellent use case for recursion. I would look recursively for the last level that has the peggingId. You already have the view to get the next level, so you if the next level returned by your view is empty, you know you have reached the end and can return that pegging id. It might be a bit annoying to write as you may have to check for each order type, and then compare the results, but from what I've heard so far that's the solution I would pursue.

Comment: Ok, I will check that recursion functions and will try for my scenario. Thanks.